# When does df.groupby(...).agg(myagg) pass a Series to myagg?

Tags: pandas

Consider the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,1,2],
                   'B':[1,2,1,2],
                   'C':list('WXYZ'),
                   'D':list('abcd')})
df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
print(df)
#    B  C  D
# A         
# 1  1  W  a
# 2  2  X  b
# 1  1  Y  c
# 2  2  Z  d

def myagg(x):
    print(type(x).__name__)
    print(x)
```

Usually, `df.groupby(...).agg(myagg)` will pass (sub)DataFrames to
`myagg`. For example,

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(myagg)
# DataFrame
#    B  C  D
# A         
# 1  1  W  a
# 1  1  Y  c
# DataFrame
#    B  C  D
# A         
# 2  2  X  b
# 2  2  Z  d
```

However, if you use a multilevel index, then myagg is passed a Series:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['B'], append=True)
df2.groupby(level=['A','B']).agg(myagg)
# Series
# A  B
# 1  1    W
#    1    Y
# Name: C
# Series
# A  B
# 2  2    X
#    2    Z
# Name: C
# Series
# A  B
# 1  1    a
#    1    c
# Name: D
# Series
# A  B
# 2  2    b
#    2    d
# Name: D
```

Sometimes this can be quite useful, but I would like to understand better 
when does `agg` pass single columns (Series) to `myagg`, and when does it pass
whole DataFrames?

Comment: I kind of think that the first one is incorrect behaviour here. It's like the popular saying: "Writing aggregation functions is hard... let's go write apply functions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prob need to go thru all of the cases, but here are some rules of thumb (assuming grouping on a DataFrame):

- If you pass a `dict` or `list` to apply, you will have item-by-item agg, IOW, you will get a `Series`
- A single aggregator passed as a string that is cythonized (e.g. `mean,sum`) will be done as a 
  `DataFrame` (you will actually get called multiple times on the different dtyped blocks)
- A function is passed, same as a single-string aggregator

Now for the gotcha.

If the passed function blows up (meaning raises a `TypeError`), this mean that it will then go item-by-item (hence you will get a `Series`)

I believe if there is a single group you will get a `DataFrame`, but again will fall-back to item-by-item if something blows up.

Answering unutbu question:

when having more than one key (e.g. the 2nd example), the default  is to aggregate with a series that has a multi-index, while a single key will do a data frame aggregation (subject to my gotcha above)

starting line 1745 in pandas/core/groupby.py

```
   if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:
        return self._python_agg_general(arg, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        result = self._aggregate_generic(arg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: builtins get Cythonized too...(so if you pass `.agg(sum)`, it'll convert it to be the same if you used `.agg('sum')`) [at least on the dev branch]

Comment: Can you point me to what in the source code causes `groupby(level=0).agg(myagg)` to call `myagg` with DataFrames, but `groupby(level=['A','B']).agg(myagg)` to call `myagg` with Series?